# Unable to find 'Maintenance Manager' in action library in Datacap Studio

Tags: ibm-datacap

I would like to use Datacap Maintenance Manager to delete batches after successful completion of batches. To determine if Datacap Maintenance Manager is a good fit for the application that my team is building, I started following [IBM Datacap guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZRWV_9.0.0/com.ibm.dc.develop.doc/dcane100.htm) to build Maintenance Manager application. One of the steps in the Maintenance Manager application guide is to expand 'Maintenance Manager' in Action library and add few Actions to functions defined in Rulesets.However, I am unable to find 'Maintenance Manger' in Action library. A quick search on the internet opened up a list of Action Libraries that comes with Datacap studio and 'Maintenance Manager' Action Library is one of them. Tried with different versions of Datacap and could not find 'Maintenance Manager' in Action Library. Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZRWV_9.0.0/com.ibm.dc.develop.doc/dcane100.htm

You can find it under the

> **NENU** actions lib in latest versions. 
>   Since 9.0.1 i guess.